# Creating an asp.net page that calls on a SharePoint 2010 Service Application

Tags: development, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to create a simple web page with three text boxes. I then pass the three values to a client for a SharePoint service application. However, when it calls on the SharePoint service application, I get an error saying it can't find the site collection. This is because platform target under Project > Properties is set to Any CPU.

Normally, when developing in SharePoint, if I get this error, I set the platform target CPU to x64 and everything works fine, but when I do that in my asp.net webpage, I get a "Could not load file or assembly 'TLAPIWebClient, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." error when I compile the webpage, as well as a few "Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly 'System.Web.dll' targets a different processor" warnings in Visual Studio.

Does anyone know how to create a 64 bit asp.net webpage that can call on a SharePoint 2010 service application?

Comment: "Any CPU" means any CPU - 64 or 32 bit.So this setting cannot cause problem with SharePoint 2010. The problem may be with the code itself.Which SharePoint service you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to work with SharePoint from remote applications is to use the Client Object Model. This solves the 32/64 bit issue.